# UISearchController in UINavigationBar push-pop view resizing without Extend Edges

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to implement a `UISearchController` with it's searchBar inside the navigationBar of a `UINavigationController`. This navigationBar has translucent and all Extend Edges turned off in Interface Builder.

The setup is quite simple:

`ViewControllerWithSearchController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. My viewController code looks like this:

```
class ViewControllerWithSearchController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

var searchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    definesPresentationContext = true
    initializeSearchController()
}

// MARK: - Search

func initializeSearchController() {

    // Create and configure the UISearchController
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Check the frame of the view
    print(view.frame)
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    // Some code here
}
}
```

When I run this, it works. The frame of the ViewController's view on initial run is `(0.0, 64.0, 375.0, 603.0)`

This viewController contains a button which pushes a generic viewController onto the stack. When I pop this viewController, the frame of the `ViewControllerWithSearchController` is unchanged (correct behavior).

However, when I activate the searchBar and then push and pop the second UIViewController (while the searchBar is active), the frame of `ViewControllerWithSearchController` gets set to `(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)`. **The view gets extended below the navigationbar, even though this behavior is turned off.**

All involved ViewControllers have their Extend Edges options turned off in InterfaceBuilder.

For now, I've implemented a workaround by turning on all the Extend Edges options. This creates a bit of overhead, so I'd rather not do it. Is there a better solution to solve this problem?

I've attached a sample project to illustrate the problem.

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxu8nvmge9vd1j3/ExtendEdgesSearchControllerTest.zip?dl=1)

Comment: I'm running into exactly this same problem and cannot come up with a good solution. What I ended up doing was to check the value of `edgesForExtendedLayout` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. If the value is `UIRectEdgeNone` but the controller's `self.view.frame` extends underneath the status bar and/or under the toolbar, I adjust `self.view.frame` right there in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Not sure it is any better than the suggested work around, but it is just another option and seems to work well.